# Show latest data from row based on custom date_field in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have 2 tables and I need to show the latest single data from row based based on due_date field in my blade file.

blade

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->statements->orderBy('due_date','desc')->get() as 
$statement)

<p> Your unpaid bill is: {{ $statement->billamount }} </p>

@endforeach
```

I get this error

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist. 
(View:...\home.blade.php)
```

EDIT

I edited the code based on the comments below:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->statements()->latest('due_date')->first() as 
$statement) 

{{ $statement->billamount }} //I only need the latest record to be shown

@endforeach
```

and it throws this error:

```
Trying to get property 'billamount' of non-object.
```

Comment: `Auth::user()->statements()->latest('due_date')->first()` should do it for you.

Comment: This throws an error saying ErrorException Undefined offset: 1

Comment: error saying your row has no billamount column check your table

Comment: table 2 has the field billamount sir. it exists under the statement table

Comment: Auth::user return only authenticated user you need send it by controller or use other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `Auth::user()->statements` to `Auth::user()->statements()`

`orderBy` is a method of Query Builder. `Auth::user()->statements` is a collection and `Auth::user()->statements` is a query builder

to show latest row data only you can use `orderBy` and `first` method. example:

```
Auth::user()->statements()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first()
```

another way use `latest` method:

```
Auth::user()->statements()->latest('created_at')->first()
```

Comment: I tried to incorporate what you mentioned

    @foreach(Auth::user()->statements()->latest('due_date')->first()) as $statement)

    {{ $statement->billamount }} 

    @endforeach

but it throws an error saying

    ErrorException
    Undefined offset: 1

Comment: You dont need foreach for a item. foreach is for collection or array

Comment: remove foreach and endforeach to `$statement  = Auth::user()->statements()->latest('due_date')->first();`

Answer (score -1):

@foreach(Auth::user()->statements()->latest('due_date')->first()) as
$statement)

when you look closely there is an extra bracket after first() so remove it and test it

@foreach(Auth::user()->statements()->latest('due_date')->first() as
$statement)

like above

also when using first you dont need to give foreach use get() rather than first()

get() return s a collection while first() returns a single record details

Comment: thank you for that. I already corrected it but it still throws an error saying    Trying to get property 'billamount'' of non-object'

Comment: when using first() dont loop ie it only has one record so $statement=Auth::user()->statements()->latest('due_date')->first(); then do $statement->billamount;